# How to sort through JSON of GeoCode get() request

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, google-geocoder

I current have the following code to process a get request and return an address.

```
address = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.8976763,-77.0387238&key=[APIKEY]"

results = httpGet(address)
console.log(results)

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
}
```

When the code executes it returns the following in a JSON format. How could I grab the "formatted_address" field from the following text?

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "1650",
           "short_name" : "1650",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest",
           "short_name" : "Pennsylvania Ave NW",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Northwest Washington",
           "short_name" : "Northwest Washington",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Washington",
           "short_name" : "Washington",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "District of Columbia",
           "short_name" : "DC",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "20504",
           "short_name" : "20504",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ]
         "formatted_address" : "1650 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20504, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 38.8980085,
           "lng" : -77.0389457
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 38.8993574802915,
              "lng" : -77.0375967197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 38.8966595197085,
              "lng" : -77.04029468029151
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJY7LRgby3t4kRz3_VtbtJpfE",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  },
}
```

I tried to process the file in a the way you would normally process a JSON file but I am still unfamiliar with the correct process. Would using something similar to

```
JSON.parse(result)
```

help when I am trying to sort through the output? Any help would be appreciated.

Similarly, how would I modify my code to work with the following snippet? Was informed that synchronous request are discouraged and I should work on creating a asynchronous request instead, but I am not aware how to integrate it.

```
 function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback)
 {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data is broken atm. But this works. Added a before formatted_address and a bracket at the bottom

```
const data = { "results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "1650",
           "short_name" : "1650",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Pennsylvania Avenue Northwest",
           "short_name" : "Pennsylvania Ave NW",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Northwest Washington",
           "short_name" : "Northwest Washington",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Washington",
           "short_name" : "Washington",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "District of Columbia",
           "short_name" : "DC",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "20504",
           "short_name" : "20504",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
    "formatted_address" : "1650 Pennsylvania Ave NW, Washington, DC 20504, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 38.8980085,
           "lng" : -77.0389457
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 38.8993574802915,
              "lng" : -77.0375967197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 38.8966595197085,
              "lng" : -77.04029468029151
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJY7LRgby3t4kRz3_VtbtJpfE",
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  },
]
}
```

get the formatted_address

```
console.log(data.results[0].formatted_address)
```

Also, you could try out request & request-promise (install both)

```
const request = require('request-promise')

request('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=38.8976763,-77.0387238&key=[APIKEY]').then(res => {
  console.log(res.results[0].formatted_address)
})
```

Comment: whenever I try to console.log() that statement I am getting an error that `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Had to JSON.parse my output before I could parse through it correctly. Ended with the following code:

```
function getAddress(){
   apiKey = "Key";
   lat = 38.8976763;
   lon = -77.0387238;
   address = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + lon + "&key=" + apiKey;

   const request = require('request-promise')
   request(address).then(res => {
   res = JSON.parse(res)
   console.log(res.results[0].formatted_address)
   })
}

getAddress()
```